# Changing order of integration for a double integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I just started dealing with double integrals, and I encountered the following question:

> Change order of integration of the following:
> $$\int^{2\pi}_{0}dx\int^{\sin(x)}_{0}f(x,y)dy.$$

So I drew the graph and tried integrating over $y$ first (meaning I take lines that are perpendicular to the $y$ axis), and got the following:

$0\leq y\leq 1$. If $0\leq x\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ then $y=\sin(x)\leq x\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$, meaning $x=\arcsin(y)\leq x\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$, and if $\frac{\pi}{2}\leq x\leq \pi$ then $x=\arcsin(y)\geq x\geq \frac{\pi}{2}$. All in all I get:

$$\int^{1}_{0}dy\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{\arcsin(y)}f(x,y)dx+\int^{1}_{0}dy\int^{\arcsin(y)}_{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(x,y)dx.$$

Is this the right way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula leads to
$$\int^{1}_{0}dy\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{\arcsin(y)}f(x,y)dx+\int^{1}_{0}dy\int^{\arcsin(y)}_{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(x,y)dx\\=
\int^{1}_{0}dy\left(\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{\arcsin(y)}f(x,y)dx-
\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{\arcsin(y)}f(x,y)dx\right)=0$$
which is not correct.

Recall that  the function $x\mapsto \sin(x)$ is not invertible on $[0,2\pi]$, and we have to pay attention when we try to solve the equation $y=\sin(x)$ with respect to $x$.

We have that
$$\int^{2\pi}_{0}dx\int^{\sin(x)}_{0}f(x,y)dy
=\int^{\pi}_{0}dx\int^{\sin(x)}_{0}f(x,y)dy-\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}dx\int_{\sin(x)}^{0}f(x,y)dy.$$
Therefore, when we change the order in the first integral we find,
$$\int^{\pi}_{0}dx\int^{\sin(x)}_{0}f(x,y)dy=
\int_{0}^{1}dy\int_{\arcsin(y)}^{\pi-\arcsin(y)}f(x,y)dx,
$$
whereas the second one is
$$\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}dx\int_{\sin(x)}^{0}f(x,y)dy=
\int_{-1}^{0}dy\int_{\pi-\arcsin(y)}^{2\pi+\arcsin(y)}f(x,y)dx.$$

Comment: How did you find the first one?

Comment: Start by drawing the two domains $\{(x,y): 0\leq x\leq \pi, 0\leq y\leq \sin(x)\}$ and $\{(x,y): \pi\leq x\leq 2\pi, \sin(x)\leq y\leq 0\}$ in the $xy$-plane. https://www.desmos.com/calculator could be helpful to find the graphs of
$\arcsin(y)$, $\pi-\arcsin(y)$ and $2\pi-\arcsin(y)$.

Comment: The thing is I did drew both domains, but for some reason it appears that when taking lines from the $y$ axis, my limits are as I wrote (atleast for $0\leq x\leq \pi$, and I can't see why what you wrote is correct)

Comment: Recall that $x=\arcsin(y) \Leftrightarrow y=\sin(x)$ for $x\in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.

Comment: So if I look at it when $x\in [\pi/2, \pi]$ I have to look at it as $\pi - arcsin(y)?$

Comment: Yes, recall that the function $x\to \sin(x)$ is not invertible on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Your answer was infact very helpful. I do have to think about it for a bit but it was very detailed. Thanks alot

Comment: I did now so I accepted your answer